# Deploy a shiny app with a development version of a package

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, lightgbm

I'm trying to deploy a shiny app in shinnyapps.io, but I have used a development version of a package (lighGBM) in the code that seems not to be recognized. It looks like shinyapps.io only works with CRAN packages.
Is there a way to deploy my app with an specific version of this package through shinnyapps.io?

Comment: did you install the package with e.g. `remotes::install_github` or similar, or from a local install?

Comment: i have installed it from source with cmake from its github repository.

Comment: If you install it locally, then shinyapps will not know where you installed it from. Use remotes::install_github, then it will find it when deploying (at least that's how it works for posit connect but I assume shinyapps.io works the same way)